# Django same url pattern different apps views

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a web application responding to two different hosts:
host_A.com
host_B.com

When host_A makes a request app_host_A.urls is used whereas when host_B makes a request app_host_B.urls is used.

Both of them have a common pattern which goes to different views.

host_A.com/test -->> goes to ->> host_A.views.test
host_B.com/test -->> goes to ->> host_B.views.test

What happens here is Django is caching de mapping between  /test  and the view itself so if I open first  host_A.com/test and then host_B.com/test, the second one opens host_A.views.test.

Comment: Do you have reloaded or restarted your webserver?

Comment: Where are you putting your logic for deciding which set of urls gets called? Maybe this will help https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1509/

Comment: The problem is not using different urlsconf ... the problem is when some of the urlconfs of different hosts have the same pattern executing different views. Django caches the pair "url pattern - app.view" so when another host uses the same pattern...django execute the cached view...